# Expression Engine - Fieldframe Error After Upgrade to 2.4

Tags: expressionengine

I upgraded an MSM site from 1.7.1 to 2.4 and while I can access the Control Panel for the sites I am unable to load the main site. I get the following error:

> Error
>
> Unable to load requested field type file:  ft.ftype_id_2.php.
>
> Confirm the fieldtype file is located in the
>   expressionengine/third_party/ directory

I have scoured the Expression Engine site, Googled it and I can't find anything that helps. As a result I am totally stumped and open to good insights.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FieldFrame is ExpressionEngine 1.x only. ExpressionEngine 2 has a built in fields API which takes its place.

Your best bet at fixing this is going into your field group settings and confirming all previous field types are installed. Have you migrated all your ee1 field types to ee2? You can make sure they are installed in ee2 by going to addons -> fieldtypes.

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for the reply. All fieldtypes are installed, but I still get the error.

Comment: Hi Phil, I did a search of the database and found one lone and obscure entry that referenced ftype_id_2. I gave it the boot and everything is working fine now. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you worked it out - it was probably some remnant from EE1 that didn't get cleaned up durring the upgrade. This sort of thing can drive a person crazy. :)

Comment: I'll agree to that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen where we're using the Master Config approach. I resolved a 500 error on the MSM site by changing config.php to use a relative path. That also had to be done in our config.php to set $base_path to a relative path. The second MSM site could not find the the third_party dir when we moved the system file above the public/web folder because $base_path was based on the second site's dir structure.